# How do I add single quote or double quote if content have a white space

Tags: php, regex

I try to make dynamic `CSS` using `PHP`.

Example on `font-family`

```
$one = 'Times New Roman, Times, serif';
$two = 'Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif';
```

On style.php

```
body { font-family:<?php echo $two; ?>; }
```

Here I want to add a single quote or double quote to the `Lucida Sans Unicode`, `Lucida Grande`

So the ouput should be

```
body { font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; }
```

Let me know how to replace the font with a quote

Comment: you could just quote every element of string, you know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more functional :-)

```
function put_quotes ($name) {
  $name = trim($name);
  return strpos($name, ' ') ? '"' . $name . '"' : $name;
}

$css = implode(', ', array_map('put_quotes', explode(',', $one)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$two = '"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif';
```

then

```
body { font-family:<?php echo $two; ?>; }
```

Comment: On db I store the font list without quote

Answer (score 1):

```
$two = 'Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif';
$aux = explode(',',$two);
foreach($aux as &$f){
    $f = trim($f);
    if(strpos($f,' ') !== FALSE)
        $f = '"' . $f . '"';
}

echo implode(', ',$aux); // "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif
```

**Edit:**
I didn't think of it, but indeed, adding the quotes to the variable `$two` (where needed) might do the trick... What happened to my [KISS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_It_Simple)?...

Comment: <del>You can shorten this with `"'".implode('", "', explode(',', $two)).'"'`.</del>

Comment: @Gumbo, Did you try your solution? this is the result: `"Lucida Sans Unicode", " Lucida Grande", " sans-serif"`. I'm not sure if it's ok to quote whitespaces before the names... Does it work??

Comment: No, you’re right, that’s not allowed: “Generic font family names are keywords and must NOT be quoted.”

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do:

```
body { font-family:"<?php echo strpos(' ', $two) !== false ? '"'.$two.'"' : $two; ?>"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$two_a = explode(",", $two);
foreach($two_a as $str) {
    $str = "'".$str."'";
}
$two = implode(",", $two_a);
```